# calculate duration for each patient.id in r

Tags: r

```
     patient.id       date type 
5           1053 2006/12/14   DX    
2           1053  2007/4/21  HSCT

1           1053  2007/5/29   FU  
6           1053  2007/7/20   FU  
3           1053  2007/9/20   FU   
4           1053 2007/11/18   D1  
7           1138   2009/9/3   DX  
13          1138   2010/2/3 HSCT  
23          1138  2010/3/11   FU  
10          1138   2010/6/6   FU   
9           1138  2010/8/31   FU   
15          1138  2010/11/5   FU   
11          1138   2011/2/7   FU   
16          1138  2011/5/15   FU   
17          1138  2011/7/18   FU   
14          1138  2011/9/21   FU   
24          1138 2011/12/13   FU   
19          1138  2012/3/13   FU   
25          1138  2012/5/11   D1
```

Comment: for example.for patient.id 1053, survival time is  2007/11/18-2006/12/14

Answer (score 1):

An R base solution:

```
> lapply(with(dat, split(date, patient.id)), function(x) diff(range(x)))
$`1053`
Time difference of 339 days

$`1138`
Time difference of 981 days
```

Comment: if the last type of each patient is HSCT or D2,  it‘s right  censored，marked as 1,   type D1 means death marked as 0. how to generate a column of such data

Answer (score 0):

Use `dplyr` to convert to date format, then group by patient and calculate max(date) - min(date).

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, "%Y/%m/%d")) %>% 
  group_by(patient.id) %>% 
  summarise(Survival = as.numeric(max(date) - min(date)))
```

Result:

```
  patient.id Survival
       <int>    <dbl>
1       1053      339
2       1138      981
```

Comment: how to calculate the days from HSCT type to the last day's type, because DX means diagnosis, HSCT means transplant.

Comment: From the second to the last data of each patient, is the patient's survival time, (HSCT) means Hematopoietic stem cell transplantation,  DX means diagnosis